# Powershell - copy files to different destination folders based on file names

Tags: powershell, copy

Dear Powershell Gurus,

I have a few thousands of files in a folder called C:\Downloads\Signs. 
The files are named with their dimensions such as 13X20 abcdjd.psf, 8X20 jdscnjfc.psf, 14X24 dje.psf etc.
What I want to do is to move these files to destination folders created within the C:\Downloads\Signs and the folder names are the dimensions of the file names. Example the folder names will be 13X20, 8X20, 14X24 etc and it depends upon as many unique file names with their dimensions. 
So, instead of moving them manually looking at how many files are there in the C:\Downloads\Signs folder and then moving them individually, how can we do it in Powershell?

Thanks,
Sanders.

Comment: JNK, honestly, I didnt try since I couldnt figure it out how to create folders by substringing the file name..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script will pick up all psf from the root of the C:\Downloads\Signs folder and will move the files to the destination folders (folders will create if they do not exist):

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Downloads\Signs -Filter *.psf | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object{

    $dest = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName $_.BaseName.Split()[0]

    if(!(Test-Path -Path $dest -PathType Container))
    {
        $null = md $dest
    }

    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $dest -Force
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shay, this is working perfect. Thanks for your quick response. What if the dimensions of the file are somewhere in the middle of the file name? say it says derf 13X20.psf or abcde 8X12.psf instead of what they are now. Do I change the split parameter within parenthesis for that? Thanks again for educating me on Powershell.

Comment: You need to be specific about the position and the command may change according to it, but to answer your question, you need to get item index 1: $_.BaseName.Split()[1] . Notice that I updated my answer to use the BaseName property and not Name, as name includes the file exention as well.

Comment: Thanks Shey. However, there are files with file names like 13X20_derf.psf too. So, in this case, I need to substring the first 5 bytes of the file names. Basically, I am looking for the syntax of substringing a file name with starting position and the length as input variables. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: $_.BaseName.Substring(int startIndex, int length)