# Powershell move folders based on part of a name

Tags: powershell, directory, move

I have bunch of folders named like that XXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX_XXXXXX_XXXX_XXXX and based on that I would like to create folders with the first part of the name (XXXXXXX) and put matching folders with the content inside the folders named XXXXXXX.

I found a script here [Script for the task for files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591985/powershell-copy-files-to-different-destination-folders-based-on-file-names) and after trying to alter it to work on folders i failed. 
Could You please give me a hint how to resolve this?
The code i was trying to alter is located below

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Downloads\Signs -Filter *.psf | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object{

$dest = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName $_.BaseName.Split()[0]

if(!(Test-Path -Path $dest -PathType Container))
{
    $null = md $dest
}

$_ | Move-Item -Destination $dest -Force}
```

Things I tried so far:
1. Apply Split() method to the table,
2. Substract the filename based on Regex and move folders into folder in the ForEach-Object.
3. The solution mentioned before works fine with the files, not with the folders.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank You in advance,

--Edit:
    Thanks to community i changed the script a little and it seems to work like 
    i wanted.

```
$location =  'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test'
Get-ChildItem -Path $location -Directory | 
Foreach-Object{

$destination =Join-Path $location $_.BaseName.Split('_')[0]

if(!(Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container))
{
    #$null = md $destination
    $null = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destination
}

$_ | Move-Item -Destination $destination -Force
}
```

Comment: `.Split()` -> `.Split('_')`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank You for the response but  using `Split('_')`won't solve the problem for folders. It works perfectly for the files though. The error i encounter is  _Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null_.

Comment: Part of your problem is that $null is a magic variable and you can't assign anything to it.  If you are wanting to suppress output, you need to, 'md $dest | out-null OR [void](md $dest).

Comment: If Join-Path is complaining about nulls then you just need to check that `$_.BaseName.Split('_')[0]` isn't null before you attempt to run Join-Path, yeah?  Although I'm curious how you're possibly getting folders in your ForEach when your Where-Object upstream is filtering out folders.

Comment: Do you have directories or files named XXXXXX_XXX_XXXXXX...? The code is looking for `.psf` files.

Comment: @lit The code is just a sample from other question i linked. I was unable to find the solution by myself so i figured out to ask here. I think that i figured out the  solution. Folders and files are almost the same, files have an extra appendix like *001.
`$location = C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test
Get-ChildItem $location  | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object{
$dest =Join-Path $location $_.BaseName.Split('_')[0]

if(!(Test-Path -Path $dest -PathType Container))
{
    $null = md $dest
}

$_ | Move-Item -Destination $dest -Force}`

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` has a `-Directory` switch which could be used to eliminate the `Where-Object` to check for it being a container.

Comment: Instead of `md`, how about `New-Item -Path "c:\" -Name $dest -ItemType "directory"`

Comment: @lit Thank you for the valuable hints.
One remark, i did `new-item` statement the different way but from what I've observed it works fine. `New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destination` Another thing: is it possible to use something instead `$null = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destination` ? I mean to make it more appropriate.

Comment: @LunaticRover - thepip3r already mentioned using `| Out-Null` rather than `$null =`.